# Fallback key expression for angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, angular-translate

Is it possible to use a "fallback key expression" for [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate)? Given the key `"share.name"`, I'd like to use `"fallback.name"`, if the first lookup fails. In general, a second lookup for `key.replace(/.*\.(\w+)/, "fallback.$1")` would be what I need. The fallback language would be the next choice.<sup>1</sup>

**Background:** I use `$translate` in the following way: For translating column names, I use the name of the entity field as translation key, e.g., when showing a list of `class Person {String firstname, lastname, birthDate, ...}`, I'd use the string `"firstname"` etc. as the key. This way I can trivially generate the header row using a loop. Moreover, I get consistent translations between tables.

Things get more complicated as sometimes I need to depart from this rule, e.g., in places where the room is too tight or for very general keys like `"name"`, which could use a context-specific translation.

<sup>1 The missing translation for the original key is not an error, it's just that the fallback translation is good enough.</sup>

Comment: have you checked the custom error handler? https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/17_custom-error-handler. That should cover your need if I didn't misunderstand your question.

Comment: @sdfacre I guess, you've got it right. I wanted to avoid the error handler for something which is not an error, but I guess, it could work. In the meantime I got a different idea avoiding this all, so my question is irrelevant now. Now, I'm allowing to specify an alternate translationID explicitly for the cases the column name can't be used.